# Help find open intervals (inc./dec.)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Finding the open intervals seems easy to me except when I stumble upon trigonometry. 
**Problem:**

> identify intervals in which the function is increasing or decreasing 
>   **f(x)=sin(x)+cos(x) $[0,2 \pi]$**
>   **My attempt**
>   I started with the derivative which is f'(x)=cos(x)-sin(x) then equaled it to zero. I'm confused as to what to do with $[0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, first we need to find when the derivative equals zero, but only on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$:

$
cos(x) - sin(x) = 0
\\
cos(x) = sin(x)
\\
x = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}
$

Now, let's look at a number line on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

> $0$-------A-------$\frac{\pi}{4}$-------B-------$\frac{5\pi}{4}$-------C-------$2\pi$

If you pick a point A such that $ 0 \lt A \lt \frac{\pi}{4} $, then if $f'(A) > 0$, then $f$ is increasing on the interval $(0, \frac{\pi}{4})$. And if $f'(A) < 0$, then $f$ is decreasing on the interval $(0, \frac{\pi}{4})$.
You can use the same reasoning with point $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Thank you so much I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

Your first instinct was correct. We consider the domain so we may identify the interval(s) on which it is increasing/decreasing. What you are given is the domain, that is, the interval the function is to be considered on. We have

$$f:[0, 2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}$$

So we consider any roots of our derivative only if they are within our domain. Clearly, since $f'(x)=\cos(x)-sin(x)$ this is equal to zero when $\sin(x)=cos(x) \Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ and perhaps a few others. . . I'll let you do the checking from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You can make life simpler if you notice that $$\sin(x)+\cos(x)= {\sqrt 2}\left(\frac {\sqrt 2}2 \sin(x)+\frac {\sqrt 2}2 \cos(x)\right)={\sqrt 2}\sin\left(x+\frac \pi 4\right)$$